# Getting 'Mountain' and other geographic entity types from Bing APIs

Tags: bing-maps

I've been trying to figure out how I can get 'Mountain' and other geographic entity types from the Bing Maps REST Location API.  Using the "Find a location by Point" returns very little information.
Perhaps using the Bing Maps REST API isn't the best place for the kind of information I'm looking for, basically natural geographic features like mountains, lakes, etc.  Any recommendations?

'Tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those types of feature (mountain, hill...) are not available inside the Bing Maps platform wether in the REST service or the Public Data Source from the Spatial Data Service (see the available categories: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478191.aspx)

In order to do so, depending on your needs, you can rely on OSM data or geonames information to retrieve information about places and known mountains/lake, see: http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=mont+blanc&country=